# Inbuilt pipes cause failures when unit testing Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, angular-pipe

I have sample component which I would like to test.
When I am using custom pipe (e.g my custom pipe `concat`) its working fine.

```
import { ConcatPipe } from 'path-to-concat-pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '{{ testProp | concat }}'
})
class TestComp {
  public testProp: Array = [2017, 2018];
}
```

But when I am trying to use [inbuilt pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=pipe) (e.g. `number`), my tests are failing without any informative error message.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '{{ testProp | number }}'
})
class TestComp {
  public testProp: number = 2017;
}
```

Sample spec code

```
describe('TestComp', () => {
    let comp: TestComp;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComp>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComp, ConcatPipe],

    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComp);        
          fixture.detectChanges();
    })
    }));

  it('TestComp successfully initialized', () => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeDefined()
  });
});
```

Also, I have tried to import DecimalPipe from '@angular/common' and add it to declarations array but it cause error

> Type DecimalPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
>   CommonModule and DynamicTestModule!

I am using angular 2.0 release version.

**UPD**

Test works fine in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aaAbqlFNCL8XBoky7Wv2?p=preview) @yurzui provided, but fails in my project. I guess issue may be related to my karma configuration files

karma.shim.js

```
'use strict';

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
require('es6-shim');
require('reflect-metadata');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');;
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('@angular/core/testing');

var appContext = require.context('./src', true, /root.spec.ts/);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');



testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

karma.conf.js

```
'use strict';

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

module.exports = function (config) {
    var _config = {
        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
            {pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: false},
            {pattern: './src/app/**/*spec.ts', watched: true, included: false}
        ],

        exclude: [],

        preprocessors: {
            './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig,

        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                {type: 'text-summary'},
                {type: 'html'}
            ]
        },

        browserNoActivityTimeout : 100000,

        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        },

        reporters: ['story', 'coverage', 'progress'],

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'], 

        singleRun: true,
    };

    config.set(_config);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
Test was failing on PhantomJS browser but works on Chrome. Same issue is reproducable for angular-cli generated projects.

For getting angular 2 builtin pipes' tests working on PhantomJS then 2 lines of code should be added to

**karma.shim.js** if you are using *generator-ng2-webpack*.

```
require('intl');
require('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en');
```

or to

**src/polyfills.ts** in the case you are using *angular-cli*.

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-what-to-declare

**What classes should I add to declarations?**

> Add declarable classes — components, directives, and pipes — to a
>   declarations list.
>
> These classes **must be declared in exactly one module** of the
>   application. Declare them in this module if they belong to this
>   module.

So you should import `CommonModule` instead of pushing `DecimalPipe` to declarations array :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [CommonModule],
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but import CommonModule didn't help, test failed again

Comment: Did you remove `DecimalPipe` from `declarations` array?

Comment: Yes I did, ``TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [TestComp]
    })``

Comment: Can you reproduce it in my plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/zobNKEmT6mnag7dBfewi?p=preview

Comment: thanks, Its working fine in your plunker, even without CommonModule import, but still dont work in my project, I guess there is an issue with my karma configuration files